# Non translation polar Limits of integration for volume of cylinder not centered at origin

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

where $D:=(x-1)^2+y^2≤1$,

How do we find $$  \iint_D dxdy?$$

I'm not sure how to find the volume of a cylinder not centered at the origin using a double integral with polar coordinates. I'm not sure how to setup the limits of integration.

Obviously, the volume of cylinder is independent of where we center it but are the bounds of integration the same as if the cylinder were centered at the origin?

Is the radius of this cylinder not centered at the origin two or one?
What I tried:

Let $ (x-1) = cos(\theta), y= sin(\theta)$

Comment: Didn't you just solve it yourself?  Translate it until it is simple since it doesn't matter.

Comment: What are the limits of the double integral without translating? Can we setup the limits of the double integral without translation? Translation confuses me.

Comment: @Randall ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite $(x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ as $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x$, which gives $r^2 \leq 2r\cos\theta$, or $r \leq 2\cos\theta$ (for $\cos\theta$ positive)

Therefore, the region is $\theta$ from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (where cosine is positive) and $r$ from $0$ to $2\cos\theta$

Comment: Ah, this seems right.

Comment: Also, +1 for the cleverness of the rewrite.

Comment: How did you get the theta $\theta$? How do you know theta doesn't go from 0 to $\pi/2$?

Comment: @Y.Forman .....

Comment: Cosine has to be positive

Comment: Also, graphically, the entire shape is to the right of the y axis

Answer (score -2):

The given inequality represents the interior of a circle with a radius 1 and centred at (1,0).

The given integral represents the area of this circle.

Limits of x will be from 0 to 2. Limits of y will be from -1 to 1.

Comment: Are the limits of the integral in polar coordinates available?

Comment: This isn't so, unless I'm seriously missing something.

Comment: We're trying to find the volume of a cylinder not the area of a circle

Comment: @Lasuiqw if you take $ x = r(1 + cos(\theta)), y= r(sin(\theta))$ then limits of theta are from -pi to pi and limits of r are from 0 to 1. You'll need to convert the integration in dxdy into drdt first though

Comment: @Lasuiqw which non existent cylinder are you referring to!

Comment: But there has to be an $r$ in your parameterizations since you are integrating over a solid region in the plane.

Comment: I think the limits of theta can be from $ -\pi$  to $ \pi$  because we're doing change of variables.

Comment: I think Y. Forman's answer is the right one

Comment: The limits cannot possibly be constants, for then it would be a semicircular wedge centered at the origin.  It isn't.

Comment: @Randall integrating given integral as it is with the constant limits I mentioned will actually find the area of a square. In Cartesian coordinates, first integrate with respect to x taking limits of x from 1+sqrt(1-y2) to 1-sqrt(1-y2). Then integrate with respect to y taking limits from -1 to 1

Comment: This is such s bad answer

Comment: The integral is indeed the area of the circle $D$, since if you “add up” (= integrate) all the area elements $dxdy$ in $D$ you get the area of $D$. But the limits given for $x$ and $y$ are all wrong, since they describe a square instead of a circle.